# I cannot update a table when other is locked

Tags: oracle

I have three tables. They are STAFF, SUBTASK and DEVICE. When STAFF is locked (`select * from staff for update`) I cannot update SUBTASK (before updating, I  have selected in STAFF). But I can update  SUBTASK when STAFF table is not locked and DEVICE table is locked.

STAFF_ID is a foreign key of SUBTASK, but I do not create constraint between two tables in Oracle and hbm file ( I am using Hibernate ).

Please explain for me. Thanks

Comment: staff_id is a foreign key of subtask, but i do not create constrain between 2 table in oracle and hbm file ( i used hibernate)

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add useful information.

Comment: Please post the ddl's of all 3 tables,

Comment: i have print sql in console of netbean. It is below "Hibernate: update Sub_Task set sub_Task_Progress = ? where sub_Task_Id = ?
Hibernate: update STAFF set STAFF_FULLNAME=?, STAFF_GRADE=?, STAFF_ROLE=?, STAFF_BIRTHDAY=?, STAFF_PHONE=?, STAFF_PLACE=?, STAFF_KNOWLEDGE=?, STAFF_TRAINED_SKILL=?, STAFF_CHARGED_OF_SKILL=?, STAFF_ORG_ID=?, STAFF_DESC=?, STAFF_CHARGED_OF_SKILL_TYPE=?, STAFF_GENDER=?, STAFF_ADDRESS=?, STAFF_MANAGER_ID=?, STAFF_HUMAN_NUMBER=?, STAFF_DEPARTMENT=?, STAFF_ORG_TRAINING=?, STAFF_STARTED_WORK=? where STAFF_ID=?"

Comment: I see that, Staff is also updated and no commit so subtask is no commit :(, but i have no call update staff

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a foreign key from subtask to staff. When you then select for update on staff, the effect is the same as if you were modifying staff. You could e.g. (1) delete a row from staff. In subtask you could (2) update the foreign key so it points to a different row of staff.

In this situation oracle cannot know whether (2) is successful or not. If the foreign key points to a staff row which was just deleted in (1) the operation can still be successful if (1) choses to roll back the transaction.

So oracle blocks (2) until (1) is committed or rolled back.

Comment: staff_id is a foreign key  of subtask, but i do not create constrain between 2 table in oracle and hbm file ( i used hibernate).